# Do the python bindings for libtorrent-rasterbar work with Python 3 ?

Tags: python, libtorrent

I have Python 3.4 (32-bit) installed, and I installed the python-libtorrent-0.16.16.win32.msi on top of that.

My test code says:
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

My google results suggest this works fine with Python 2.7.  Is that the solution? I have to down-grade my Python?

Comment: There do exist a [debian package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python3-libtorrent) and a [pull request](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python3-libtorrent) which do what you want, so in theory it should be possible. Note however, that this doesn't necessarily imply that it will be easy on Windows. However, it's easy for Pythons 2 and 3 to coexist- it's not a downgrade since you should be able to install both Python 2 and Python 3 alongside each other.

Comment: the binaries are built against python 2.7. If you build it yourself, you can most likely get it to work on python 3

Comment: Despite the answer below, the bindings from the Debian package `python3-libtorrent` are now working fine.  Give them a try.

Comment: Recent versions of libtorrent compiles and works fine with python 3. But I couldn't find valid installer. So you probably have to compile it by hand. I've just done it with MSVS 2010 Express. More detailed instructions how to build it you can find at official [website](http://libtorrent.org/)

Answer (score 1):

NO. Libtorrent doesn't support Python 3.

It compiles but doesn't work due to Python 3 utf8 handling difference.
There was an unsuccessful effort to make it work a while back
https://code.google.com/p/libtorrent/issues/detail?id=449

Current trunk even contains invalid Python 3 i.e.
http://sourceforge.net/p/libtorrent/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/bindings/python/setup.py
Line 70 > 'print cmdline'

For some reason there is an Ubuntu python3-libtorrent package which confuses people, but it definitely doesn't work, neither does manual compilation.

```
steps:
apt-get build-dep libtorrent-rasterbar
export 'PYTHON_VERSION=3.4'; export 'PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.34'
./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m-x86_64-linux-gnu/" --enable-python-binding --enable-geoip=no
--with-boost-python=boost_python-py34
ldconfig

>> python
import libtorrent
ses = libtorrent.session()
ses.save_state()

"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa2 in position 0: invalid start byte"
```

Comment: _For some reason there is an Ubuntu python3-libtorrent package which confuses people, but it definitely doesn't work, neither does manual compilation._ How nice, typical opensource.

Comment: I've used libtorrent with Python 3 so you should probably update your answer to reflect the current state in case folks come across it. The issues have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It does support python3

This docker file works for me (`libtorrent` - local dir with the lib been checked out to version needed)

```
FROM debian:buster-slim

WORKDIR /app/libtorrent
COPY debian/backports.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y -t buster-backports checkinstall
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libboost-system-dev libboost-python-dev libboost-chrono-dev libboost-random-dev libssl-dev
RUN apt-get install -y autoconf automake libtool
ADD libtorrent /app/libtorrent
RUN ./autotool.sh
# RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 1
ENV PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.7
RUN ./configure --enable-python-binding --with-libiconv
RUN make
RUN checkinstall
RUN ldconfig
```