# Does libtorrent work in Python 3?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, libtorrent

I've tried everything over the last few days to install libtorrent in Python3. No matter what I try, I get:

```
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 13 2017, 12:02:49) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libtorrent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libtorrent'
```

I get no errors when I run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-libtorrent
$ sudo apt-get install libtorrent-rasterbar-dev
```

I don't really understand the difference between libtorrent, and libtorrent-rasterbar. As far as I can tell rasterbar is a dependency for libtorrent.

The [PyPi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-libtorrent/1.1.0) doesn't have any binaries on it, so I can't `pip install` it.

I can download the package from [the GitHub page](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/releases) and install it that way by running:

```
$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py install
```

Which creates:

```
/home/<user>/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/python_libtorrent-1.1.5-py3.6.egg-info
```

But still no change. It may have something to do with my Python3 install not being in a default location, but I'm not sure how to handle that in terms of installing libtorrent.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073609/do-the-python-bindings-for-libtorrent-rasterbar-work-with-python-3) similar SO question where the accepted answer is a definitive NO. However, there are more recent comments that say that, since then, it has become possible, except no instructions are given on how to achieve it.

I am thoroughly running out of ideas and am open to any suggestions no matter how ridiculous. Right now, I'm looking through the package I got from the GitHub page to see if I can somehow copy the code into my project directory, and then import it as a local module, but I'm not having much luck so far. If that doesn't work, I'll look at writing my own Python3 wrapper for the original C++ libtorrent library. However, I read somewhere that someone else tried and failed at this, so I'm not expecting success.

EDIT:

Okay, I've gotten a little further. I somehow managed to download a version of the repo that did not have a configure file, or any of the makefiles. Now that I have the right one, I run:

```
$ ./configure --enable-python-bindings
$ make
$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py install
$ python 
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 13 2017, 12:02:49) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libtorrent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.62.0: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type
```

I Googled this, and apparently PyClass_Type is not defined in Python3. So it seems that it's still trying to build itself for Python2, which explains the `libboost_python-py27.so` in the ImportError. The suggested solution was to compile the C++ libraries with `-lboost_python3` instead of `-lboost_python`. Line 268 of the Makefile is `BOOST_PYTHON_LIB = -lboost_python` so I changed it to `BOOST_PYTHON_LIB = -lboost_python3` and re-ran:

```
$ make
$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py
```

(I can't re-run `$ ./configure --enable-python-binding` because it reverts the Makefile to use lboost-python again). Unfortunately, I still get the same error message: `undefined symbol: PyClass_Type`. I know next to nothing about C++, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something really obvious about compiling the library.

Comment: the "27" in libboost_python-py27.so.1.62.0 refers to python version 2.7. You need to have boost-python built for python 3.x as well

Comment: Thanks for the response @Arvid. I downloaded boost from http://www.boost.org/ and built it according to the instructions here: https://eb2.co/blog/2012/03/building-boost.python-for-python-3.2/ the `project-config.jam` listed my python path as `using python : 3.6 : /home/<user>/anaconda3 ;` so I don't think I need to change it. I then re-ran the commands to build libtorrent. Unfortunately, I still get the same error.

Comment: btw, you are the libtorrent dev, right? I saw your posts on a lot of SO questions about libtorrent as I was troubleshooting. Thanks so much for building such a complete library for torrent related stuff. It's great to have a dev that continues to help people after they've built it. Not to mention if I can get it working, you will have saved me however many weeks it would take to hack together a far crappier version

Comment: @Arvid I was trying to install the libtorrent in conda env using the steps provided http://dreamingpotato.com/2015/11/21/how-to-install-python-libtorrent-in-virtualenv/. But I am getting same issue in the original question. Can you guys provide the steps setup the libboost on python 3.3 in conda virtualenv? I follwed the steps in this post https://gist.github.com/melvincabatuan/a5a4a10b15ef31a5a481 and added the conda virtualenv python 3.3 paths. But still getting the same errors.

Comment: @VaibhavBhavsar As far as I know, it's not possible to set up libtorrent in conda. I've tried with no success. Your best bet is to use the default python install, but you might run into trouble with the virtualenv as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I have solved it. It turns out I had two separate installations of Python3. The default one, and the Anaconda one. Furthermore, when I installed Anaconda, I let it add itself to my `$PATH` environment variable. I hadn't noticed I wasn't using the default install because I was still able to install packages through pip etc. Basically, stuff that was pure Python worked fine. However, since libtorrent is a Python wrapper on top of a C++ library, running `$ ./configure --enable-python-binding` built all the Python bits to my Anaconda Python install, and all the C++ bits to my default Python install (or something like that, from what I can tell).

The solution was to uninstall Anaconda: `$ sudo rm -rf ~/anaconda3`, and delete the `$PATH` variable Anaconda set in my `.bashrc`.For good measure I also, `$ sudo apt-get remove`'d and `$ sudo apt-get purge`'d every library I had installed that had anything to do with libtorrent. I can't remember all of them, but it definitely included `python3-libtorrent`, `python-libtorrent`, `python3-libboost`, and `python-libboost`. Once I'd done that, a simple `$ sudo apt-get install python3-libtorrent` got it working perfectly.

@Arvid, Just as a side note, for me at least the last line of the print statement in the [python example](http://www.libtorrent.org/python_binding.html#using-libtorrent-in-python) needed to be changed from:

```
s.num_peers, state_str[s.state])
```

to simply:

```
s.num_peers, s.state)
```

since `s.state` held a string representing the state, not an integer that needed to be mapped to the `state_str` list. That could be just a consequence of how Python3 handles states though; I haven't tested it in Python2.

Comment: I had a similar problem: didn't work on python3.6 or python 3.8 but did work on python3 :/